# top vertical-align with inline-block and horizontally identical margins

Tags: css

This CSS code makes two columns of box arranged in a larger container. Basically this works great but it has one problem - the boxes on each row are **NOT** horizontally centered. The margin on the left box is smaller than right margin of the right side box. I need to make them same.

```
    #container {
        width:  20pc;
        height: 40pc;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
    }
    .box {
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        width: 45%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
```

The piece of html is

```
<div id="container">
  <p class="box">Displays an element as an inline-level block container. The inside of this block is formatted as block-level box, and the element itself is formatted as an inline-level box</p>
  <p class="box">The values "inline-table", "table", "table-caption", "table-cell", "table-column", "table-column-group", "table-row", and "table-row-group" are not supported in IE7 and earlier. IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE. IE9 supports the values.</p>
  <p class="box">This may be the best technique overall, simply because the height can vary with the content and browser support is great. The main disadvantage is the extra markup, requiring a total of three elements to get the final one centered.</p>
  <p class="box">Displays an element as an inline-level flex container. New in CSS3</p>
</div>
```

I've tried these css properties `justify-content: space-around; align-self: center; align-item: center; margin: auto`, but all of them have no effects to solve this problem.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/98BRm/). I can't even solve it by setting a fixed identical left and right margin to the left and right boxes respectively. The height of the boxes are dynamic, and the number of the boxes is either odd or even. My final goal is to make it really look like a two columns of box.

Please help give me a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding `text-align: center;` to your `#container` CSS?

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/98BRm/1/

Comment: Yes, this partially resolve the problem. One thing I forgot to mention is when this is odd number of boxes inside the container, then it doesn't look good since the last one is aligned center. And the height of the box is not all same, so it may look ugly sometimes.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to add a relevant example of this? (In case of an odd number of boxes, try adding a placeholder element with the same properties as the box, except for the borders.)

Comment: Would this fiddle be what you want? http://fiddle.jshell.net/98BRm/4/
Although in that case you wouldn't really need the left/right classes.

Comment: Yes, the idea of placeholder is smart.